# Is jquery worth a try with an asp.net webform application?

Tags: jquery, webforms

Hai guys,
  I ve been using javascript to get my validations,effects and so on... Now i ve decide to use jquery in one of my webform application

1. Is **jquery** worth a try with an asp.net webform application?
2. Will ajax update panel be an issue for me when using jquery?

I ve studied that the **ready event** will not fire for an asynchronous postback caused from UpdatePanel control...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, if the application has lots of javascript functionality you may take benefit of the numerous plugins
2. No, jQuery has a [compatibility mode](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries).
3. [jQuery.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event fires only when you reload the page and the DOM is ready for manipulation. For asynchronous postbacks of UpdatePanels use:

   ```
   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager
               .getInstance()
               .add_endRequest(endRequest);

   function endRequest(sender, args) {
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Go with jQuery. Never look back. May the force be with you.